# `location` in Angular `location.path` returns a blank string

Tags: angularjs, location

I am trying to change the color of the entries of the navigation menu, to indicate which is the current page. But the `location.path` is returning a blank string.  I get no other errors.

```
var mflfApp = angular.module("mflfApp", []);

mflfApp.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function (destination) {
        // This function should indicate if the path provide in the destination correspond to the current 
        // locaiton.  This is then used to highlight an option in the navigation menu

        //  $location.path(); contains a blank string.  But does not throws an error.
        return destination === $location.path();
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return destination === $location.path();
```

if you just pass, what string you are getting in `destination` variable as:

```
return destination === $location.path(destination);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: $location.path(destination) returns the path of the page passed as Destination.  My purpose was to identify what was the current page.  I finally did that using absUrl().  Though in that case I received the complete string and for my purposes had to remove the unwanted characters.